# How it is possible using Kotlin function features make this piece of code nicer?

Tags: android, kotlin, functional-programming, kotlin-android-extensions

I have these piece of codes and I don't like that I have mapNotNull and inside I have else cases which returns null, I think my kotlin knowledge is not enough to make it better, any thoughts?

```
    return config.mainMenus.mapNotNull { mainMenu ->
      val subPage = config.subPages.find {
        if (mainMenu.actions.isNotEmpty()) {
          it.id == mainMenu.actions.first().contentId
        } else {
          false
        }
      }
      if (subPage?.items?.isNotEmpty() != null) {
        MenuItem(mainMenu.type, mainMenu.titles, mainMenu.actions[0].type, subPage.items)
      } else {
        null
      }
    }
  }


  val programs = cards.mapNotNull { card ->
              if (card is Program) {
                epgRepository.getProgramProgress(currentTime = currentTime, program = card)
              } else {
                null
              }
            }
```

Comment: Do you think splitting the code into functions would make the code look nice? Also, please read about [scoping functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/scope-functions.html). I highly recommend them as they improve code readability.

Comment: You should at least explain what Type do you want to return. and you can take a look at Kotlin Elvis Operator. I suggest you should not insist to just use one `return()` if you need so many indent in it. I think readability is more important when you co-op with others than writing fancy piece of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the previous code with

```
            return config.mainMenus.mapNotNull { mainMenu ->
        config.subPages
                .find{mainMenu.actions.firstOrNull()?.contentId?.equals(it.id)?:false}
                ?.let{menu->
                    MenuItem(mainMenu.type, mainMenu.titles, mainMenu.actions[0].type, menu.items).takeIf{menu.items?.isNotEmpty()==true}
                }?:null
    }
}
```

Te second one could be

```
  val programs = cards.
      filterIsInstance<Program>().
      map { epgRepository.getProgramProgress(currentTime = currentTime, program = card)}
```

In this case you firstly filter the collection getting only the elements that are programs and only those are converted to the type that the function getProgramProcess return

Comment: having cast in filter{} doesn't effect when I do map because card considers Card type again

Comment: ok you are rigth instead of filter you should use filterIsInstance. I have edited my answer